# How to escape backticks in string literal

Tags: go

I have a slack payload that would format to markdown. And I'm trying to figure out how to preserve the backtick

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`{
  "channel": "#edtest",
  "username": "snapshot",
  "attachments": [
        {   
            "mkdwn": true,
            "text": "`this backtick doesn't work`",
        }
    ]
}`)
```

if you look at the text field, that backtick won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't escape backticks. When there's long text like this, one thing you can do is to replace them:

```
var jsonstr=[]byte(strings.Replace(`{
Some json string with ^backticks^
}`,"^","`",-1))
```

Another option is to add string segments:

```
var jsonstr=[]byte(`{
Some json string with `+"`backticks`"+`
}`)
```